# Why did Jack leave some money for Walt?

Tags: character, breaking-bad, plot-explanation

Why did Jack leave a barrel of money for Walt? This happened towards the end of Season 5! Did Jack take pity on Walt because he was dying of cancer again? Or did he try to make sure Walt didn't come after him in the future?